# Is it possible to use MathTex() and Text() alternately without always creating a new Mobject?

Tags: python, text, latex, manim

Optimize code for using `MathTex()` and `Text()` alternately in Manim

I would like to have the following output (image).[image]

For this output, my code is as follows:

```
class ZWSAufgabe(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        Text.set_default(font="Poppins", color=BLACK, line_spacing=3)
        MathTex.set_default(color=BLACK)

        def custom_text(string, **kwargs):
            text = Text(string, **kwargs)
            text.scale(.5).set_stroke(BLACK, 0)
            return text
        
        def custom_mtex(string, **kwargs):
            text = MathTex(string, **kwargs)
            text.scale(.75)
            return text
        
        aufgabe1 = custom_text("Zeige, dass die Funktion").to_edge(UL)
        aufgabe2 = custom_mtex(r"f(x) := sin(x) - e^{-x}").next_to(aufgabe1, RIGHT)
        aufgabe3 = custom_text("im Intervall").next_to(aufgabe2, RIGHT)
        aufgabe4 = custom_mtex(r"[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]").next_to(aufgabe3, RIGHT)
        aufgabe5 = custom_text("genau eine Nullstelle besitzt.").next_to(aufgabe1, DOWN, aligned_edge=LEFT)

        self.play(Write(aufgabe1))
        self.play(Write(aufgabe2))
        self.play(Write(aufgabe3))
        self.play(Write(aufgabe4))
        self.play(Write(aufgabe5))
        self.wait()
```

How can I improve my code so that I don't always have to write so much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, but not by utilizing `Text()` but `Tex()` for the typesetting of the text. Then you can switch with `$..$` or `\(..\)` between math mode and text mode.

Using XeTeX you could also use your desired font easily for the typesetting in `Tex()` - come over to [Discord](https://manim.community/discord) where it is easier to answer these questions in a forum.

There also ways to improve the typesetting and layout by using different LaTeX environments and commands here.

```
class ZWSAufgabe(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        #Text.set_default(font="Poppins", color=BLACK, line_spacing=3)
        #MathTex.set_default(color=BLACK)

        aufgabe = Tex(r"Zeige, dass die Funktion $f(x) := sin(x) - e^{-x}$\\ im Intervall $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ genau eine Nullstelle besitzt.").to_edge(UL)
        aufgabe.scale(0.75)
        self.play(Write(aufgabe))

        self.wait()
```

So using XeTeX, a left-aligned layout and your Poppy-font the solution could look like this:

```
class ZWSAufgabe(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        Tex.set_default(color=BLACK)
        self.camera.background_color = WHITE
        myTexTemplate = TexTemplate(
            tex_compiler="xelatex",
            output_format='.xdv',
        )
        myTexTemplate.add_to_preamble(r"\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{Poppins}\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}")
        
        aufgabe = Tex(
            r'''Zeige, dass die Funktion $f(x) := sin(x) - e^{-x}$\\ 
            im Intervall $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ genau eine Nullstelle 
            besitzt.''',
            tex_template=myTexTemplate,
            tex_environment="flushleft"
        ).to_edge(UL)
        aufgabe.scale(0.75)
        self.play(Write(aufgabe))
```

[image]

Comment: That worked. But unfortunately not for my font 'Poppins'.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you so much, this will save me a lot of time and effort in the future.